# Make an stored procedure using sql server 2005 that allows paging

Tags: sql-server

I have the following SQL Query:

```
DECLARE @Page int, @RegistriesPerPage int , @FirstRegistry int, @LastRegistry int
Set @Page=1
Set @RegistriesPerPage=2
Set @FirstRegistry = (@Page - 1) * @RegistriesPerPage
Set @LastRegistry = (@Page * @RegistriesPerPage +1)


SELECT I.ID, Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC) as Counter
FROM Items I
WHERE Counter > @FirstRegistry AND Counter < @LastRegistry

group by Id,Name
```

Im trying to make it work, but aparently i cannot cause i cannot use "Counter" on the where clause (even the ROW_Number().

How i could create stored procedure that gets two parameters (number of items per page, and page to return)?

Comment: Don't.  Use Linq2SQL or EF.  And you can use a HAVING instead of the selected answer's subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use derived query :

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT I.ID, Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC) as Counter
  FROM Items I      
  group by Id,Name
)a
WHERE Counter > @FirstRegistry AND Counter < @LastRegistry
```

Comment: Ah, ok. I see. The thing is that i have to make a select from a select in order to do it right?

Comment: yeah. In this case you will be able to use field aliases from your original query in `WHERE`.

Comment: Or you can also do the same with CTE if you prefer it over derived query - no difference from performance point of view in this case.